# Showing lognormal distribution in stock prices

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, distribution

I have the following price data on a particular stock. Using `df.head()`, I have:

```
             Adj Close  pct_change   log_ret
Date                                        
2018-01-02  167.701889    0.017905  0.017746
2018-01-03  167.672668   -0.000174 -0.000174
2018-01-04  168.451508    0.004645  0.004634
2018-01-05  170.369385    0.011385  0.011321
2018-01-08  169.736588   -0.003714 -0.003721
```

The pct_change is obtained using `df['pct_change'] = df['Adj Close'].pct_change()` while the log_ret is derived using `df['log_ret'] = np.log(df['Adj Close']) - np.log(df['Adj Close'].shift(1))`.

First, I show that the daily returns of the stock is normally distributed:

```
plt.hist(df['log_ret'].loc[df.index >= '2018-01-01'], 100)
plt.show()
```

[image: Distribution of daily returns of the stock]

Since the daily returns of the stock is normally distributed, the price of the stock should follow a `lognormal distribution`. If I interpret it correctly, it means log(['Adj Price']) ~ N(mean,var). Hence, I created a new column `log_price` and tried to plot the following:

```
df['log_price'] = np.log(df['Adj Close'])
plt.hist(df['log_price'].loc[df.index >= '2018-01-01'], 100)
plt.show()
```

[image: Distribution of log(Adj Close) of the stock]

However, it does not seem that the prices follow a lognormal distribution. I want to show that the prices follow a lognormal distribution, so what am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score -2):

Source:[Log-normal_distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)

**if Y has a normal distribution, then the exponential function of Y, X = exp(Y), has a log-normal distribution**

but in your code you have taken log which is wrong, so correct the code, for more details follow the wikipedia.